# 500 internal error

Tags: php, html, apache

I have 2 php-files at my server.
Second's name is `secret.php`, first one is `index.php`.

In index file I have a form which looks like:

```
<form action="secret.php" method="post">
   <!-- ... -->
   <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

Everything worked before, but when I added a few changes into form code (added another input elements, etc) I got an error: 500.

I looked with FireBug and got such picture:

```
POST http://server.com/secret.php 500 Internal Server Error
```

Post params are right.

I also can't direct access of that file. Any ideas? I remember one time again: it worked well until I've added some code into form.

File permissions are right too.

Comment: Does it work again of you remove the added code?

Comment: So you changed it from *unspecified* to *unspecified*. That doesn't give us much to go on. Read the server logs and see what the error actually is.

Comment: i can suggest to take a look to apache error log , it will specify the   unspecified

Comment: post the server-side code you have now (the part you modified) and what you had before otherwise this question is likely to be closed

Answer (score 2):

A [`500 error`](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E500.html) indicates that something has gone wrong on the server. Usually it's an error which the server cannot recover from and it just gives this response by default.

If your server keeps logs, then look at those. The cause of the problem is likely going to be recorded there. Also have a look at your secret.php file, and how it handles your input as that is likely the root of the cause.

Just some additional info: By default the apache log files are kept under `/var/log/httpd/error_log` on linux.